# How can I places objects to specific facial landmarks ? like ears and hats

Tags: unity, augmented-reality

I'm currently trying multiple AR plugins in unity and I'm stuck in how to place certain objects in specific landmark positions.
I used the landmark positions to spawn certain objects but they are way off from the intended areas I wanted.

Here is the code sample I'm using the get the facial landmarks of the ears, mouth, nose and eyes :

```
MatOfPoint2f imagePoints;
imagePoints = new MatOfPoint2f ();
Mat rgbaMat = webCamTextureToMatHelper.GetMat();
Rect detectionResult = faceLandmarkDetector.Detect();
List<Vector2> points;
if(detectionResult != null && detectionsResult > 0)
    points = faceLandmarkDetector.DetectLandmark(detectionResult[0]);
if(points != null)
{
imagePoints.fromArray(
new Point((points[38].x + points[41].x) / 2, (points[38].y + points[41].y) / 2), //Left Eye Facial LandMark Position
new Point((points[43].x + points[46].x) / 2, (points[43].y + points[46].y) / 2),// Right Eye
new Point(points[30].x, points[30].y), //Nose
new Point(points[0].x, points[0].y),Left Ear
new Point(points[16].x, points[16].y) Right Ear

);
}
```

Comment: How are you detecting these locations at present?

Comment: I'm using facemask, found it on the unity asset store, I want to find a way to use their 68 facial landmark points to place objects on the face.

Comment: Great. For users who aren't familiar with this asset, please show a minimal sample of your code where you're reading these landmark points. Including information on what coordinate space they're in would also be helpful.

Comment: @DMGregory I modified the question and added a code sample.

Comment: So, presumably you tried instantiating your props and setting their positions to those screen points? Where did that go wrong?

Comment: Yes, I spawned the objects using these landmark points but they are way off from the area I wanted,

Comment: Great. That's another detail that should be in your question. Show the code you used to do that and the result, and how it differs from what you want. The more information you share about where you're at, the better folks can target answers to fixing the spots you need help with.